# JavaScriptSerializer won't recognize date string as DateTime?

Tags: c#, javascript

here is my model:

```
public class ReportAllMediaDetailsParams
    {
        public int profileID  { get; set; }
        public int organisationID { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
}
```

here is my deserializer:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var reportParams = serializer.Deserialize<ReportAllMediaDetailsParams>(json);
```

the date that is coming from json is:

```
"{\"profileID\":\"41\",\"organisationID\":\"2252\",\"startDate\":\"01/01/1970\",\"endDate\":\"01/01/1970\"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

- Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer`, use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) instead.
- Don't use locale specific formats such as `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy` in JSON.  For example, does `1/4/2013` represent the first day of April? Or the fourth day of January?  There's no way to know.
- Use  ISO8601 format instead.  It is culture-invariant, so there is no ambiguity.
  In ISO format, you have `2013-01-04`, which is *always* `yyyy-mm-dd` so there is no ambiguity.  A full datetime would be `2013-01-04T05:30:27.123` for example.
- Coming from C#, use `DateTime.ToString("o")` to get this format - or just use Json.Net which automatically serializes `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` using the ISO format.

Comment: using the ISO8601 was the solution in my case http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp